# How to gracefully close File/Stream/Seq in FSharp when grabbing multiple lines?

Tags: f#

I'm trying to write a class in FSharp to lazily read in lines from a text file and convert them into the appropriate Record types.  My records are multiple lines long, so I use Seq.take function to pull off as many lines as I need at a time - in this case 4.

```
let readLines = seq {
    while not inputStream.EndOfStream do
        yield inputStream.ReadLine()
    inputStream.Close()
}

let lineQuartet readLines = Seq.take 4 readLines
```

The problem I'm having is that when I run out of lines, instead of ending there, I'm getting empty seqs which cause the reader to crash.

What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit unclear what you're asking, but if you want a more 'robust' alternative to `Seq.take`, you can use `Seq.truncate`:

```
let lineQuartet readLines = Seq.truncate 4 readLines
```

It will return at most 4 elements.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can also be solved with a take that is more tolerant of missing elements.

```
let tryTake n (sq : _ seq) =
        let e = sq.GetEnumerator()
        let i = ref 0
        seq {
            while e.MoveNext() && !i < n do
                i := !i + 1
                yield e.Current
        }
```

(adapted from [this link](http://www.fssnip.net/1K))